# what does '0n0' mean?

Tags: windbg

What does `0n0` mean in windbg ? My `windbg` is showing all local variables with `0n1500` etc..

Comment: n is for .net number :) **just kidding!**

Comment: It's short for "Oh, No! Don't make me use windbag!"

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It ('0n') is the number prefix used to indicate a decimal representation in windbg. It allows the non-prefixed to be used for hexadecimal, for instance.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 12):

It's [MASM syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff552157%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for decimal, like 0x for hex.

Answer (score 2):

`0n` represents the **base 10**, ie. the number being displayed after n is in **decimal notation**.

[Possible values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/masm-numbers-and-operators#numbers-in-debugger-masm-expressions) for this:
`0n` - Decimal 
`0x` - Hexadecimal  
`0t` - Octal  
`0y` - Binary

You can change the default display base (radix) for numeric data display and entry using [`n` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/n--set-number-base-).

`n16` - Change base to Hexadecimal  
`n10` - Change base to Decimal  
`n8` - Change base to Octal

Note that `n2` is not allowed.

The following is taken from WinDBG command window while debugging a program.
I am trying to get OS build number from its PEB (Process environment block).
I am using Win10 19044 build.

```
0:000> n 16
base is 16
0:000> ?? @$proc->OSBuildNumber
unsigned short 0x4a64
0:000> n 10
base is 10
0:000> ?? @$proc->OSBuildNumber
unsigned short 0n19044
0:000> n 8
base is 8
0:000> ?? @$proc->OSBuildNumber
unsigned short 0t45144
```

Note that this will work only for numeric data types, and other types, such as pointers will still display in Hex, no matter what argument you use with `n`.

```
0:000> n 8
base is 8
0:000> ?? @$proc->ImageBaseAddress
void * 0x00007ff6`6dfa0000
0:000> n 10
base is 10
0:000> ?? @$proc->ImageBaseAddress
void * 0x00007ff6`6dfa0000
0:000> n 16
base is 16
0:000> ?? @$proc->ImageBaseAddress
void * 0x00007ff6`6dfa0000
```

`ImageBaseAddress` is of type void * (pointer type), hence is unaffected by `n` command.
We can obviously do an explicit type cast.

```
0:000> n 10
base is 10
0:000> ?? DWORD(@$proc->ImageBaseAddress)
DWORD 0n1845100544
0:000> n 16
base is 16
0:000> ?? DWORD(@$proc->ImageBaseAddress)
DWORD 0x6dfa0000
```